# How do I return the next available appointment given the following structure in PHP and SQL?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

My problem is much more complicating than your usual retrieving the next available date in a booking system. I have the following structure for the table which could look like this with data:

```
user_id   day        time_from   time_to   date
1         Thursday    09:00      17:00     NULL
1         Friday      09:00      17:00     NULL
1         NULL        09:00      17:00     05-12-2019
```

There are two types of slots. The user is able to insert weekly recurring slots by 'day' and individual slots by 'date'. I am able to retrieve the next available '**date**' quite easily and the result is correct and similarly, if I was to retrieve the next available recurring day and then turn it into the next date in the week it can be done using `PHP`.

My issue is when I try to combine the two and attempt to calculate the next available date by checking for both the recurring days in the week as well as the closest date to the current date. For some odd reason it always prints Thursday (even if I have no slots set for the day on the back end) which leads me to believe the issue lies within the `SQL` query.

Here's my current SQL query:

```
    $this->db->select('day, date');
    $this->db->from('partner_availability');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
  $this->db->where("(date >= NOW())");
    $this->db->order_by("date ASC",
"(
 CASE
      WHEN day = 'Sunday' THEN 1
      WHEN day = 'Monday' THEN 2
      WHEN day = 'Tuesday' THEN 3
      WHEN day = 'Wednesday' THEN 4
      WHEN day = 'Thursday' THEN 5
      WHEN day = 'Friday' THEN 6
      WHEN day = 'Saturday' THEN 7
 END), day ASC"); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

And the PHP code to print the desired result (keep in mind the query above is in a model and in-between the view and the model is the controller (**MVC Codeigniter PHP Framework**):

```
<p style="text-align:center;">Next available appointment: <span style="color: #801424; font-weight: bold;">
<?php
$recurring_day = $partner_availability_date[0]['day'];
day = date('l', strtotime($recurring_day));
$date_in_week = strtotime( 'next '. $day);

$ind_day= strtotime($partner_availability_date[0]['date']);
$difference = $date_in_week - $ind_day;

   if(count($partner_availability_date) > 0) {
        if($difference < 0){
            echo date('D jS', $date_in_week);
        }else {
            echo date('D jS', strtotime($partner_availability_date[0]['date']));
        }
   }else
   {
    echo "N/A";
   }
?>
</span></p>
```

Any assistance with this issue is greatly appreciated! Thanks! I hope I explained it well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `where` clause is going to fail, and dates aren't going to return as the date you think they are.

mySQL dates are in the format yyyy-mm-dd and you have dates stored in your date column as dd-mm-yyyy.

Check your column definition for `date` is actually a DATE type, then retest.